# Window Server 2016 Datacenter is unable to automatically trigger the action

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server, taskscheduler, windows-server-2016

Good afternoon!
Recently I have created a Window Server 2016 Datacenter. One of my tasks is to run my own application on a schedule(every 5 minutes). In order to test whether "task scheduler" works properly a try to launch calculator and set triggers.

The problem is that when a complete all the setup, the scheduler writes the next time when he will run the calculator, but when the time comes nothing happens. However after refreshing the scheduler writes that it was successfully launched, but it fact it wasn't. Furthermore the calculator open if I run it manually.
[that's what the scheduler shows, but in fact it does not happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIfto.png)

> If its necessary I can provide any additional details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have the same issue and just decided to use an older version of windows for scheduled tasks. Hopefully, Microsoft fixes this at some point. I am not sure where to put the bug report.

Comment: Found it, *finally*. When creating a Trigger for a new task, in Windows 2016, the 'Enabled' checkbox is not ticked by default. If you leave the trigger disabled by accident you get exactly the described behavior.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience with Windows 2016 Standard edition with latest Updates as of today,  the issue seems to be that if the Start time of the Trigger is missed (even when "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" is ticked) then it will not run at Repeat interval either.

The work around is to ensure that you set the Start time in the future, and if you ever edit the Scheduled Task, make sure you change the Start time/date so it is again in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the exact same issue on Windows 2016 Server. Using this workaround now: change "Begin the task" from "On a schedule / daily" to "At startup". This way, the "repeat task every" x minutes works OK.

Answer (score 1):

I have a support agreement and called in about this issue.  It's been confirmed internally as a bug and they are working on a fix.  I was given a tentative resolution time-frame of July/August.

The same question is also asked on ServerFault, where I also posted this answer.
https://serverfault.com/questions/821184/windows-server-2016-scheduled-task-schedule-must-be-in-future/849574#849574

*Mods - At my reputation level, I am unable to flag anything as duplicate (and not sure if it counts as duplicate between StackOverflow.com vs ServerFault.com)*

Comment: Would you happen to know if there's a Microsoft Connect issue for this bug? If so could you post the link?  I'd like to pile on about it. Thanks.

Comment: I was never given a tracking number for this, but this issue seems to be fixed at this point, at least in my own testing.  I don't know when it was specifically fixed, but I think it may be as of the August cumulative patch, but if not it was definitely following the September patch.

Answer (score 0):

For me is working the next solution.
Change trigger task settings to the next configs:
Begin task: On a schedule
Settings: One time
Advanced settings: Repeat task every N minutes,
                   for a duration of Indefinitely
Enabled: true

On Task General tab: set checkbox Run with the highest privileges,
Configure for: Windows 7, server 2012

Answer (score -1):

By the way, if you ever change anything for the scheduled task, you will need to reset the start time for, for example, the time you want it to start the next day.

For example, we have a task that begins at 1AM and runs until 11:55PM, repeating every 10 minutes.  So, If I need to change at 9:15AM, I need to change the start time to 1AM TOMORROW, then test it manually today.  If I want it to run today, I need to manually run it every 10 minutes (so much for a task scheduler).

Then, it looks like I need to come in at 1AM tomorrow morning to make sure the task scheduler starts it correctly and doesn't harmfully interact with anything that is also running.  (it is really not very reliable in Win 2016)

I don't want the set the "start at" time to 9:20AM, because I need it to start at 1AM (business dictates this).

I consider this new behavior a bug.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question, I found that it contributed to an understanding of the situation.